# How to import module contained in my customized module into python interactive environment's namespace?

Tags: python, module, namespaces

I write the below module myinit.py:

```
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime
```

And copy it into search path.

```
sudo cp init.py  /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/myinit.py
```

Now enter into my python's interactive environment with python in cmd.

```
import myinit
dir(pd)
NameError: name 'pd' is not defined
dir(pandas)
NameError: name 'pandas' is not defined
dir(myinit.pd)
<module 'pandas' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py'>
```

In my current python cmd environment,i have two ways to call pandas.

1. Call it with `myinit.pd`
2. Input `import pandas as pd` in current python cmd environment,then call it with `pd`.

Both of them make me uncomfortable,there is no `os, np ,pd ,datetime` in current python namespace.
how to  call module imported by my customized module with itself's name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import myinit` imports the entire `myinit` module, but it only adds *one name* to the local namespace: `myinit`.

Now, `myinit` may itself contain names like `pd`, `np`, `os`, and `datetime` (as well as any variables/functions you've defined within it), but they're *inside* `myinit`. So, to access them, we need to do

```
import myinit
dir(myinit.pd)
# <module 'pandas' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py'>
```

Essentially, namespaces are nested like this. We use dot notation to descend from namespace to namespace (e.g. `pandas` has its own namespace, `pandas.DataFrame` has its own namespace, and so on down the line).

You can import *a specific name* from a different module by using `from`:

```
from myinit import pd
dir(pd)
<module 'pandas' from '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pandas/__init__.py'>
dir(os)
# error - we didn't import os, only pd
```

And the way to import *every name* contained within a different module into the local namespace, as you seem to be trying to do, is with an asterisk:

```
from myinit import *
dir(pd)
dir(os)
...
```

Though you can do this, you shouldn't - per PEP 22, "Explicit is better than implicit", and you should be clear on exactly what names you're using from a given import.

---

By the way, don't worry about importing the same module twice (like `pandas`) in two different files. It only ever gets loaded into memory once - the `sys` module contains a cache of previously-loaded modules throughout the program, and if you try to load a module anywhere in your program that has been loaded before, it just picks the same reference from that cache instead of loading a whole new instance.

Importing `pandas`, or `os`, or pretty much any other module, in multiple files in your program, is better code style, as it makes it more clear what tools you're using and where they come from.